# Weak property is set to nil in dealloc but property's ivar is not nil

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I noticed the following in Objective-C with ARC enabled:

Let's have simple class A and autosynthesized weak property

```
@interface A
@property (nonatomic, weak) id refObject;
@end

@implementation A
@end
```

And second class B with dealloc implemented

```
@interface B
@end

@implementation B
-(void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"In dealloc");
}
@end
```

And finally somewhere in class A have the following:

```
@implementation A
...
-(void) foo
{
   B* b = [B new];
   self.refObject = b;
   // Just use b after the weak assignment
   // in order to not dealloc 'b' before assignement 
   NSLog(@"%@", b);
}
...
@end
```

If I set a breakpoint in `[B dealloc]` and inspect `[A refObject]` property I can see that `a.refObject` is nil but `a->_refObject` is not nil and points to 'b'

Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: Maybe the accessor method returns `nil` when it knows the weak ref should be cleared, but the instance variable itself is left intact (and deallocated, and now it's a dangling pointer).

Comment: I think that in dealloc the object is still valid and not deleted yet. You unregister it for example from NSNotificationCenter and can access its properties.

Comment: "you can access it" doesn't necessarily mean it's not deallocated, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Short answer:** The instance variable `a->_refObject` is not (yet) nil in `-[B dealloc]`,
but each access to that weak pointer is done through a ARC runtime function
that returns nil if the deallocation has already begun.

**Long answer:** By setting a watchpoint you can see that `a->_refObject` is set to nil at the end of the
deallocation process. The stack backtrace (when the watchpoint is hit) looks like this:

```
frame #0: 0x00007fff8ab9f0f8 libobjc.A.dylib`arr_clear_deallocating + 83
frame #1: 0x00007fff8ab889ee libobjc.A.dylib`objc_clear_deallocating + 151
frame #2: 0x00007fff8ab88940 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 121
frame #3: 0x00007fff8ab88fa0 libobjc.A.dylib`object_dispose + 22
frame #4: 0x0000000100000b27 weakdealloc`-[B dealloc](self=0x000000010010a640, _cmd=0x00007fff887f807b) + 151 at main.m:28
frame #5: 0x0000000100000bbc weakdealloc`-[A foo](self=0x0000000100108290, _cmd=0x0000000100000e6f) + 140 at main.m:41
frame #6: 0x0000000100000cf5 weakdealloc`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbff968) + 117 at main.m:52
frame #7: 0x00007fff8c0987e1 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

and `object_dispose()` is called from `-[NSObject dealloc]` (as can be seen in
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm).

Therefore in `-[B dealloc]`, `a->_refObject` is not nil before the (compiler generated) `[super dealloc]` is called.

So the question remains: Why does `a.refObject` return nil at that point?

The reason is that for each access to a weak pointer the ARC compiler generates
a call to `objc_loadWeak()` or `objc_loadWeakRetained()`. From the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-loadweakretained):

> **id objc_loadWeakRetained(id *object)**
>
> If object is registered as a __weak object, and the last value stored into object has not > yet been deallocated or begun deallocation, retains that value and returns it. Otherwise > returns null.

So even if `a->refObject` is not nil at that point, accessing the weak pointer
via `objc_loadWeakRetained()` (as done by the property accessor method) returns nil,
because the deallocation of the `B` object has already begun.

The debugger accesses `a->refObject` directly and does not call `objc_loadWeak()`.

Comment: Noce thanks. I thought that each time weak pointer is accessed the compiler adds objc_loadWeak but seems that is not the case with a->_refObj

Comment: @plamkata__: The *compiler* adds `objc_loadWeak[Retained]` for each access to `a->refObject`, only the *debugger*  accesses the ivar directly.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was under the impression that when I observed that behaviour I was using NSLog in the dealloc method to dump the ivar and that was what confused me. But actually I was not using NSLog but debugger instead so as you mentioned it access it directly. Thanks again for the help.