# Weak reference to an object being dealloced is nil, before dealloc is done

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Let's say B holds weak reference to A, and A has strong to B

in **A**'s dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [self.b foo];
    self.b = nil;

}
```

in **B**'s foo

```
- (void)foo {

   NSLog(@"%@", self.a);
   //using self.a weak reference to A, which is nil; 

}
```

**Why is the weak reference not nil AFTER dealloc is done? What is the reason for this, and can i prevent it? Is there maybe some method that is called right before dealloc?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weak property is set to nil in dealloc but property's ivar is not nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122347/weak-property-is-set-to-nil-in-dealloc-but-propertys-ivar-is-not-nil)

Answer (score 0):

Two inconsistencies:

1.A) In your code you state:

> ... weak reference to A, which is nil

1.B) In your question, you state:

> … why is the weak reference not nil

According to 1.A) above, it is nil as expected.

---

2.A) In your question you state

> … AFTER dealloc is done

2.B) In your code you call a function `foo` in the dealloc method

Foo is not executed after dealloc is done. Dealloc is done once you return from the dealloc method. Also, you are not calling `[super dealloc]` which is OK if using ARC, but it would be missing if you were not using automatic reference counting.

Comment: but when A is calling B's foo, than B's weak pointer on A is already nil, even, when the A's dealloc didn't finish yet

Comment: When dealloc is called, A terminates all weak pointers to itself, while it still has available its own strong pointers.

Comment: yes, but how to avoid that... or is there a method which gets called before dealloc, where weak references to A dont hold nil yet?

Comment: A weak reference does not imply responsibility or ownership. Thus you can never rely on it not being nil. See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW30) on this.