# Temporal relation between `dealloc` and breaking of weak references [Cocoa]

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, weak-references

What is the temporal relation between the execution of `dealloc` and the point where weak references are broken and where entries are removed from an `NSMapTable`?

In particular, can I be sure that when `dealloc` starts to execute, there are no strong references left from the point of view of the application, and that no new strong references can be obtained (except maybe by copying `self` during the execution of `dealloc`)?

Comment: I would strongly expect so yes, but I cannot say I have seen this documented by Apple.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems like all strong and weak references are broken by the time dealloc is reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can be sure.

The explanation is clearly stated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16123880/3265733).

The gist of it is that the resolution of a weak reference is often done implicitly through a low-level API that takes into account whether the deallocation has already started for the instance pointed at by the reference.