# How to avoid EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when indirectly accessing weak ivar from inside dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I have an Objective-C layer that wraps a C++ component. The current design is meant to be robust, meaning that the user may set the instance to nil anytime (ARC) and the underlying component will clean itself up properly, and synchronously.

The problem I have is that the Obj-C instance on top passes itself to the underlying C++ layer as a __weak reference to be accessed during operation (e.g. calling delegate, changing some states, etc.) and when a user deallocs the Obj-C instance by setting it to nil, an EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when trying to access it from inside dealloc.

Here's some sample code solely to demonstrate the problematic scenario.

**Wrapper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Underlying.h"

@interface Wrapper : NSObject {
    Underlying* _cppUnderlying;
}

- (instancetype)init;
- (void)dealloc;

@end
```

**Wrapper+Private.h**

```
#import "Wrapper.h"

@interface Wrapper () {
@package
    NSMutableDictionary* _dict;
}

@end
```

**Wrapper.mm**

```
#import "Wrapper+Private.h"

@implementation Wrapper

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    _cppUnderlying = new Underlying(self);
    _dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    delete _cppUnderlying;
}

@end
```

**Underlying.h**

```
@class Wrapper;

class Underlying
{
public:
    Underlying(Wrapper* wrapper);
    ~Underlying();

private:
    __weak Wrapper* _wrapper;
};
```

**Underlying.mm**

```
#include "Underlying.h"
#import "Wrapper+Private.h"

Underlying::Underlying(Wrapper* wrapper) :
    _wrapper(wrapper)
{
}

Underlying::~Underlying()
{
    // ERROR OCCURS HERE.
    [_wrapper->_dict setValue:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
}
```

Initially, the question was "Why the error?!" but then, I just found out about this: [Weak property is set to nil in dealloc but property's ivar is not nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122347/weak-property-is-set-to-nil-in-dealloc-but-propertys-ivar-is-not-nil) which includes a detailed explanation (basically, objc_loadWeak() returns nil as soon as dealloc starts).

Now, the question would be:
What kind of Obj-C design practice could I adopt to avoid this situation altogether? The C++ layer takes care of all session cleanup (if any ongoing) synchronously in its destructor. It seems like the same cannot be done in Objective-C. Should I provide a 'release' or 'close' method to asynchronously do all the cleanup before the user is ALLOWED to dealloc the instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about inside `-[Wrapper dealloc]`, before you do `delete _cppUnderlying;`, you first call something like `_cppUnderlying->cleanup(_dict);` where you explicitly pass your dictionary, or even `_cppUnderlying->cleanup(self);` where you pass the entire object, and let the `Underlying` take care of all the cleanup there?

Comment: That would've made sense, but the underlying C++ code is a library in itself with an API that cannot be changed. Usually, is it considered good practice to do cleanup synchronously within the dealloc or I should expose an async release method to handle all that, before the user can dealloc?

Comment: @XanderLo: but you added a `__weak Wrapper* _wrapper;` variable to the `Underlying` class, so you have already made changes to it

Comment: Finally, I went ahead with internally checking for nil and add a method at the Obj-C API layer to asynchronously terminate everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're dereferencing `nil` with the `->` operator:

```
[_wrapper->_dict setValue:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
```

Either test `_wrapper` for nil, or change make `dict` into a property you can access via dot notation:

```
if (_wrapper) {
    [_wrapper->_dict setValue:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
}
```

or

```
[_wrapper.dict setValue:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
```

Comment: I know that I could check for nil, but then I'd be concerned about concurrency and non-deterministic behaviour. The sample code above is for reproducing only, but the actual code is more complex with some C++ cleanup code happening in a different thread while the C++ dtor waits.

It seems the same cannot be done (nor is recommended) in Obj-C dealloc. That's why I was inquiring about the best design practice for cleaning up an Obj-C object before deallocating it. Thoughts?