# Swift weak reference is nil when that object's deinit is executing

Tags: swift, weak-references

I found a interesting thing:

```
class A {
  let name = "A"

  deinit {
    print(self.name)
    print(self === Weak.value)
    print(Weak.value?.name ?? "nil")
  }
}

enum Weak {
  static weak var value: A? = nil
}

var a = A()
Weak.value = a
a = A() //to call deinit
```

Output is

```
A
false
nil
```

So, when an object is executing its deinit method, it can access its own properties. But another weak reference to this object has become of nil even this object has not been deallocated actually at this time.

According to [This article](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html), there is a side-table of each object. Here is my assumption: When an object's deinit method is executing, this object hasn't been deallocated. But the pointer from this object's side-table, to this object, has already been removed (or marked as nil). So no one can access it except itself. This is actually how Swift 4 works.

Is what I said right? This post is not a question, just want more details. It's so kind if someone can explain more.

Comment: For Objective-C that was investigated here: [Weak property is set to nil in dealloc but property's ivar is not nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122347/weak-property-is-set-to-nil-in-dealloc-but-propertys-ivar-is-not-nil).

Comment: Print `Weak.value` instead of the `name`.

Comment: @user1046037 Same result. It's not important. BTW, I'm implementing observer pattern actually, I need observer can remove itself from observers array in subject which maintains a weak reference to observers. It needs sth like `self === Weak.value` but it doesn't work. But I've solved this in another way.

Comment: @MartinR It's... a little hard for me to read something like the stack backtrace or totally understand objc's system for now. Should learn more to interpret it :P Thank you for reply!

Comment: Hi @ribilynn, I have the same issue. What was the way you have solved it? By using the same approach or completely another?

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi I’m not sure what you are meaning “issue”. If you are talking about observer pattern, I introduced a class like ‘WeakReference’ that just holding a weak reference to the actual class I cared about. Then let subject holding a ‘WeakReference’ array. When that array’s count changed, filter the array to clear the ‘WeakReference’s that has no object holding. It’s a stupid way I wrote in 2018, for now I will use Combine.